# Using a class instance as a class attribute, descriptors, and properties

Tags: python, class, properties, descriptor, new-style-class

I have recently stated trying to use the newer style of classes in Python (those derived from object). As an excersise to familiarise myself with them I am trying to define a class which has a number of class instances as attributes, with each of these class instances describing a different type of data, e.g. 1d lists, 2d arrays, scalars etc. Essentially I wish to be able to write

```
some_class.data_type.some_variable
```

where `data_type` is a class instance describing a collection of variables. Below is my first attempt at implementing this, using just a `profiles_1d` instance and rather generic names:

```
class profiles_1d(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y1=None, y2=None, y3=None):
        self.x = x
        self.y1 = y1
        self.y2 = y2
        self.y3 = y3

class collection(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._profiles_1d = None

    def get_profiles(self):
        return self._profiles_1d

    def set_profiles(self, x, *args, **kwargs):
        self._profiles_1d = profiles_1d(x, *args, **kwargs)

    def del_profiles(self):
        self._profiles_1d = None

    profiles1d = property(fget=get_profiles, fset=set_profiles, fdel=del_profiles,
        doc="One dimensional profiles")
```

Is the above code roughly an appropriate way of tackling this problem. The examples I have seen of using `property` just set the value of some variable. Here I require my set method to initialise an instance of some class. If not, any other suggestions of better ways to implement this would be greatly appreciated.

In addition, is the way I am defining my set method ok? Generally the set method, as far as I understand, defines what to do when the user types, in this example,

```
collection.profiles1d = ...
```

The only way I can correctly set the attributes of the `profiles_1d` instance with the above code is to type `collection.set_profiles([...], y1=[...], ...)`, but I think that I shouldn't be directly calling this method. Ideally I would want to type `collection.profiles = ([...], y1=[...], ...)`: is this correct/possible?

Finally, I have seen a decorators mentioned alot with repect to the new style of classes, but this is something I know very little about. Is the use of decorators appropriate here? Is this something I should know more about for this problem?

Comment: Why use getters and getters and a private attribute? Just make `profiles_1d` a public attribute and have the code setting it pass a `profiles_1d` object instead of parameters for the constructor.

Comment: As a user surely it would be easier to just deal with the main class (`collection` in this case). But you're right, this would be an easy solution.

Comment: your `collection` already returns objects of `profiles_1d` type to the code using it; it violates the principal of least surprise for a setter to pass something different from what a getter returns (not to mention getters and setters being thoroughly unpythonic).

Comment: @Wooble Thanks - I'll bear this in mind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, it's good you're learning new-style classes. They've got lots of advantages.

The modern way to make properties in Python is:

```
class Collection(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._profiles_1d = None

    @property
    def profiles(self):
        """One dimensional profiles"""
        return self._profiles_1d

    @profiles.setter
    def profiles(self, argtuple):
        args, kwargs = argtuple
        self._profiles_1d = profiles_1d(*args, **kwargs)

    @profiles.deleter
    def profiles(self):
        self._profiles_1d = None
```

then set `profiles` by doing

```
collection = Collection()
collection.profiles = (arg1, arg2, arg3), {'kwarg1':val1, 'kwarg2':val2}
```

Notice all three methods having the same name.

This is not normally done; either have them pass the attributes to `collection`s constructor or have them create the `profiles_1d` themselves and then do `collections.profiles = myprofiles1d` or pass it to the constructor.

When you want the attribute to *manage access to itself* instead of the class managing access to the attribute, make the attribute a class with a descriptor. Do this if, unlike in the property example above, you actually want the data stored inside the attribute (instead of another, faux-private instance variable). Also, it's good for if you're going to use the same property over and over again -- make it a descriptor and you don't need to write the code multiple times or use a base class.

I actually like the page by @S.Lott -- Building Skills in Python's [Attributes, Properties and Descriptors](http://homepage.mac.com/s_lott/books/python/html/p03/p03c05_properties.html).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it is very helpful. However, presumably the argument `x` should not be in the line `self._profiles_1d = profiles_1d(x, *args, **kwargs)`?

Answer (score 1):

When creating `property`s (or other descriptors) that need to call other instance methods the naming convention is to prepend an `_` to those methods; so your names above would be `_get_profiles`, `_set_profiles`, and `_del_profiles`.

In Python 2.6+ each property is also a decorator, so you don't have to create the (otherwise useless) `_name` methods:

```
@property
def test(self):
    return self._test

@test.setter
def test(self, newvalue):
    # validate newvalue if necessary
    self._test = newvalue

@test.deleter
def test(self):
    del self._test
```

It looks like your code is trying to set `profiles` on the class instead of instances -- if this is so, properties on the class won't work as `collections.profiles` would be overridden with a `profiles_1d` object, clobbering the property... if this is really what you want, you'll have to make a metaclass and put the property there instead.

Hopefully you are talking about instances, so the class would look like:

```
class Collection(object):  # notice the capital C in Collection
    def __init__(self):
        self._profiles_1d = None

    @property
    def profiles1d(self):
        "One dimensional profiles"
        return self._profiles_1d

    @profiles1d.setter
    def profiles1d(self, value):
        self._profiles_1d = profiles_1d(*value)

    @profiles1d.deleter
    def profiles1d(self):
        del self._profiles_1d
```

and then you would do something like:

```
collection = Collection()
collection.profiles1d = x, y1, y2, y3
```

A couple things to note:  the `setter` method gets called with only two items: `self`, and the new `value` (which is why you were having to call `set_profiles1d` manually); when doing an assignment, keyword naming is not an option (that only works in function calls, which an assignment is not).  If it makes sense for you, you can get fancy and do something like:

```
collection.profiles1d = (x, dict(y1=y1, y2=y2, y3=y3))
```

and then change the `setter` to:

```
    @profiles1d.setter
    def profiles1d(self, value):
        x, y = value
        self._profiles_1d = profiles_1d(x, **y)
```

which is still fairly readable (although I prefer the `x, y1, y2, y3` version myself).